# Cannot find class o.quarkus.amazon.lambda.runtime.QuarkusStreamHandler when invoking Quarkus Lambda

Tags: quarkus

I followed the online Quarkus guide for creating a Quarkus AWS Lambda function, using Quarkus 2.16. Instead of using the initial maven command the project was created with the Eclipse Quarkus add on using the extension quarkus-amazon-lambda. I was able to successfully deploy the Quarkus lambda function in AWS using the AWS cli.  However when I try to invoke the lambda function through the AWS CLI it returns this error:

{"errorMessage":"Class not found: o.quarkus.amazon.lambda.runtime.QuarkusStreamHandler","errorType":"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException"}

I saw a similar question posed in 2019 and it stated to add "quarkus.package.uber-jar=true" in application.properties (which is now "quarkus.package.type=uber-jar") but this did not resolve the problem.

Here are the dependencies in the pom.xml (which was automatically generated):

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-amazon-lambda</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure the following things are correct

- You have to mention
  the handler name as this and don't change. `io.quarkus.amazon.lambda.runtime.QuarkusStreamHandler::handleRequest`
- In your deployment, check which zip/jar deployed. You should deploy the function.zip instead of jars that were generated by the quarkus.
- If you try to invoke your function by ALB, you should add dependency `quarkus-amazon-lambda-rest' instead of` quarkus-amazon-lambda`. Additionally, you have to create a rest controller instead of implementing a custom request handler.

Please let me know if the issue still exists.

Comment: Thanks, I made a typo and missed the first "i" for the handler for "io.quarkus.amazon.lambda.runtime.QuarkusStreamHandler::handleRequest".  The online Quarkus start guides do not work (the maven archetypes do not create complete project templates). So far I got the template working doing this from the command lines: mvn io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:2.16.3.Final:create -DprojectGroupId=org.webber -DprojectArtifactId=quarkus-aws-lambda -Dextensions="quarkus-amazon-lambda-rest"